# Static Variable & For Loop

Tags: c++, static

I've produced a minimum reproducible example of my problem:

```
#include <iostream>

void Func()
{
    static int i = 0;

    for (i; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Func();
    Func();
    Func();
}
```

The output from this is "0", "0", "0". I want it to output "0", "1", "2". How do I achieve this?

Comment: What purpose does the loop serve?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux In the above code it doesn't serve a specific purpose - it's simply an example of my problem. In the actual code I'm working on I'm trying to perform some calculations, "exit" out of the function, draw the result, and then continue.

Comment: me: *reads question, formulates answer, goes to post, sees "there are 4 new answers to this post", sighs*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `Func()` `return`s immediately after `i` is printed out, `i++` (as the *iteration_expression* of `for` loop) is not evaluated at all.

You might want (even the loop seems meaningless here, the function always `return`s at the 1st iteration) :

```
void Func()
{
    static int i = 0;

    for (;i < 5;)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
        i++;
        return;
    }
}
```

Or

```
void Func()
{
    static int i = 0;

    for (;i < 5;)
    {
        std::cout << i++ << "\n";
        return;
    }
}
```

PS: I'm not sure about your intent, but as @FrançoisAndrieux and @Jarod42 commented, using `if` or `while` seems to make more sense, if you want `i` to be increased everytime `Func()` is called but won't be larger than `5`.

Comment: Wow you beat me by 50 seconds :-)

Comment: @Vlad Sorry. :)

Comment: That `for` loop might as well be an `if` instead.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! I've been wracking my brain for ages trying to figure this one out and I knew it was some part of C++ that I wasn't understanding properly.

Comment: You removed unneeded increment, but keep for-init noop. :/ so `for` becomes `while` which might be `if`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, it seems making much more sence.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: `for (static int i = 0; i < 5;)
    {
        std::cout << i++ << "\n";
        return;
    }` so `for` is useful to scope `i` :-) but can also be done with `if` since C++17.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sorry for the type. Got fixed (thanks to Jarod42).

Answer (score 3):

Your [for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) is equivalent to:

```
while (  i < 5 ) {
    // loop body
    std::cout << i << "\n";
    return;
    // increment
    i++;    
}
```

In other words, you never modify `i` because you `return` before. You can get the wanted output if you rearrange the above `while` loop (or get rid of the loop altogether).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `for` loop is that it *never* reaches its end (the `return` statement prevents that). Thus, the `i++` operation, which would be executed *after* the body of the loop completes, is never being used.

To achieve your desired output, but keeping the `for` loop, you would need something like the following code (but this makes the loop even more bizarre):

```cpp
void Func()
{
    static int i = 0;
    for (; i < 5; ) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
        i++;
        return;
    }
}
```